# Can i make a pre-approval key for only one time use in PayPal?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am making a system in which first user grants a pre approval permission. Then admin will use that pre approval key and make a chain payment and deducts his commission. I know about the starting date and ending date for pre-approval key. But i want to make use of a pre-approval key only once. Admin can only use that key for one-time if transaction completes after that the key should be expired. How can i do that. Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: PayPal uses the term preapproval for arrangements where the buyer approves future payment(s). While you don't give a lot of specifics in your question, depending upon timeframes you may want to just either use a payment token (agreement to pay once) or, if the payment will be delayed beyond the timeframe of a payment experience, using an Order? The buyer approves an order, which is then fulfilled & paid; the order is marked complete & "consumed."